# FindInstance returns Indeterminate in version 9, but not in 8

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Here is a trivial system of equations in three unknowns for which `FindInstance` obtains a solution:

```
FindInstance[
 c3 + c2 == 1 && c1 == 0 && -c2 == 0, {c1, c2, c3}]

(* ==> {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 1}} *)
```

But in my application, I have a linear system where I want to rule out the trivial solution `c1==c2==c3` with an inequality:

```
FindInstance[
 (c3 != 0 || c2 != 0) && c1 == 0 && -c2 == 0, {c1, c2, c3}]

(* ==> {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> Indeterminate, c3 -> 1}} *)
```

This incorrectly returns `Indeterminate` for `c2` only in *Mathematica* version 9, whereas it gives a correct result `c2 -> 0` in version 8. In general, my variables are complex so that I can't restrict the domain to `Reals` (which solves the problem in this simple example).

My current solution to this issue is to replace the inequality by an equation, e.g., `Norm[{c1, c2, c3}] ==1`. But I would like to understand (if at all possible) what change between versions is causing the `Indeterminate` result. I have a version-8 notebook that suddenly produced `Indeterminate` in over half its calculations, and there is no documented change in `FindInstance` that I'm aware of. So I'd like to hear what the safest and/or most efficient way would be to rule out the trivial solution in `FindInstance` for a system of linear equations.

Comment: Here's a workaround: For some reason, *Mathematica* only returns the `Indeterminate` if you ask for 1 result. Ask for 2 and take the first one.

Comment: @Xerxes That's funny. But then my workaround with `Norm` still gives a simpler result.

Comment: I will second Adam's "thanks for pointing it out".

Comment: Sorry for taking the [tag:version-9] off, but I thought that was the policy adopted in [this meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/how-should-we-tag-longstanding-bugs-that-have-been-fixed/1364#1364).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, I wasn't aware of that, or maybe forgot. It's OK - I'll remove the tag again. Too bad we don't have a real bug tracker.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem can be fixed with the following patch (you can put it
in your init.m file).

```
Unprotect[Internal`FromCoefficientList];
Internal`FromCoefficientList[cfs_List, 0] := If[cfs==={}, 0, cfs[[1]]];
Protect[Internal`FromCoefficientList];
```

Resolving the problem:

```
FindInstance[(c3 != 0 || c2 != 0) && c1 == 0 && -c2 == 0, {c1, c2, c3}]
(* {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 1}} *)
```

Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I tried it on about twenty different systems of equations, and everything is back to what it looked like in version 8. So the problem seems to be solved. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange, Adam.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to surround this with `If[$Version == 9, ...]` to avoid trouble after any future upgrades (since users will likely keep their `init.m` but might forget about modifications).

Answer (score 3):

On v10.0.0,

```
In[1]:= FindInstance[(c3 != 0 || c2 != 0) && c1 == 0 && -c2 == 0, {c1, c2, c3}]

Out[1]= {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 1}}
```