# What is the inverse of CoefficientList?

Tags: polynomials

I have numbers in vector notation. I need to get polynomial notation from them.

My numbers are `{0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0}`. I want to get $x + 23x^2 + 5x^3 + 15x^4$ from this list.

How can I get that polynomial?

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21340/dynamic-application-of-several-polynomials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One straightforward approach is to calculate the answer directly:

```
Total[{0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0} x^(Range[8] - 1)]
```

Answer (score 16):

The following (taken from the *Mathematica* documentation) will do what you ask.

```
Expand[FromDigits[Reverse[{0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0}], x]]
```

> x + 23 x^2 + 5 x^3 + 15 x^4

I found the needed code in *Properties & Relations* section of the documentation page on [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientList.html). In general, it is a good idea to look for information on inverses in the *Properties & Relations* section of any function of interest.

Answer (score 15):

The undocumented function `` Internal`FromCoefficientList `` is as close as one would get to `InverseCoefficientList`.

Examples:

```
cl = {0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0};
Internal`FromCoefficientList[cl, x]
```

> x + 23 x^2 + 5 x^3 + 15 x^4

```
cl2 = CoefficientList[(1 + x + 2 y)^2, {x, y}]
```

> {{1, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}

```
FullSimplify[Internal`FromCoefficientList[cl2, {x, y}]]
```

> (1 + x + 2 y)^2

See also: [this answer by Adam Strzebonski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20860/121) (thanks: Mr. Wizard for the reference)

Timings using @Mr.Wizard's set-up and `timeAvg`:

```
n = 5000;
c = RandomInteger[30, n];

Expand[Fold[(#1 \[FormalX] + #2) &, 0, Reverse[c]]] // timeAvg  (* 3.250000 *)
Expand@FromDigits[Reverse@c,  x] // timeAvg                     (* 0.039375 *)
MapIndexed[#1*x^(#2 - 1) &, c] // Total // timeAvg              (* 0.019375 *)
Total[c*x^(Range@n - 1)] // timeAvg                             (* 0.005375 *)
c.(x^Range[0, n - 1]) // timeAvg                                (* 0.003875 *)
Internal`FromCoefficientList[c, x] // timeAvg                   (* 0.003500 *)
```

Comment: First mentioned on Stack Exchange [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20860/121) as far as I can tell. +1 for posting it in a place people can find it.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.W for the link and the vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the link, I was able to update that original bug.

Comment: Just to add on how could this be done with documented functions: `rules = (#2 - {1}) -> #1 & @@@ MapIndexed[Rule, cl]; FromCoefficientRules[rules, x]`.

Answer (score 9):

`Dot` can be very efficient here:

```
c.(x^Range[0, Length@c - 1])
```

> ```
> x + 23 x^2 + 5 x^3 + 15 x^4
> ```

Comparative timings:

```
n = 5000;
c = RandomInteger[30, n];

SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

Expand @ FromDigits[Reverse@c, x] // timeAvg
Total[c * x^(Range@n - 1)] // timeAvg
MapIndexed[#1*x^(#2 - 1) &, c] // Total // timeAvg
c.(x^Range[0, n - 1]) // timeAvg
```

> 0.03616
>
> 0.004992
>
> 0.01744
>
> 0.003616

I also like this formulation though it is not quite as fast:

```
c.Array[x^# &, n, 0]
```

Answer (score 6):

I vastly prefer using Horner for reconstructing polynomials from their coefficients. To wit:

```
Fold[(#1 \[FormalX] + #2) &, 0, Reverse[{0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0}]] // Expand
```

returns your polynomial. In fact, this is effectively what `FromDigits[]` does internally for integer digits. Removing the `Expand[]` yields what would've been the result of applying `HornerForm[]` to the polynomial.

Comment: Why do you prefer `Fold` to `FromDigits` or `Dot`?  Also you can drop the second argument of `Fold`; see: [(54784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)

Comment: Elegant demonstration of a fundamental programming construct.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, re: `Fold[]`, old habits, I guess (I still don't have a computer, much less version 10). Anyway, as I said, this is what is done internally in `FromDigits[]`; I thought it'd be a nice showcase for Horner. As is well-known, Horner minimizes the number of multiplications necessary for evaluating a polynomial, in contrast to an explicit monomial expansion.

Comment: Fair enough. +1

Comment: +1 Answering questions without a viable Mma installation is a NKC. (The C being challenge)

Comment: @bel, it stresses my powers of imagination, surprisingly. Who'd have thought? ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
MapIndexed[#1*x^(#2 - 1) &, {0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0}] // Total
```

(*  {x + 23 x^2 + 5 x^3 + 15 x^4}  *)

Comment: I was expecting direct command :(. This works pretty enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
mycoeff = {0, 1, 23, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0};
FromCoeff[lst_, x_]:=Plus@@(lst*x^(Part/@Range[Length[lst]]-1));
FromCoeff[mycoeff, x]
```

Comment: I think something was copied incorrectly.  Specifically `Part /@ Range[Length[lst]]` does not make sense.

Comment: I guess it's working now, but `Part/@` appears vestigial.  Also you are pretty much duplicating bill's Accepted answer. :-/