# Reconstructing a polynomial from its coefficient array

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

A polynomial coefficient matrix:

```
mat = 
  CoefficientList[3 + 5 x^3 + 4 y^3 + 2 x + 6 x^2 y + 7 x y^2 + 8 x y, {x, y}];
```

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 2 & 8 & 7 & 0 \\
 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Another matrix:

```
list = 
  {{a1, b1, c1, d1}, {e1, f1, g1, h1}, {i1, j1, k1, l1}, {m1, n1,o1, p1}};
```

whose matrix form is:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a1 & b1 & c1 & d1 \\
e1 & f1 & g1 & h1 \\
i1 & j1 & k1 & l1 \\
m1 & n1 & o1 & p1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

How can I generate the following polynomial automatically?

$\text{a1}+\text{d1} y^3+\text{e1} x+\text{f1} x y+\text{g1} x y^2+\text{j1} x^2 y+\text{m1} x^3$

Comment: Why are some entries of the matrix ignored?  Maybe this, if that is a mistake: `{{a1, b1, c1, d1}, {e1, f1, g1, h1}, {i1, j1, k1, l1}, {m1, n1, o1, p1}}.y^Range[0, 3].x^Range[0, 3]`

Comment: There's an example in the docs for `CoefficientList` for how to recover the polynomial from the matrix: Look for `Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, %, {x, y}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am ignoring only those entries for which the constant is zero as in coefficientlist matrix.

Comment: Do you mean `Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, Unitize@mat * list, {x, y}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Exactly.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(22392)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22392/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mat` as the template:

```
Plus @@ Flatten[Table[If[mat[[i, j]] == 0, 0, list[[i, j]] x^(i - 1) y^(j - 1)], 
   {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]]
(* a1 + e1 x + m1 x^3 + f1 x y + j1 x^2 y + g1 x y^2 + d1 y^3 *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Internal`FromCoefficientList[mat, {x, y}]
```

> 3 + 2 x + 5 x^3 + 8 x y + 6 x^2 y + 7 x y^2 + 4 y^3

```
Internal`FromCoefficientList[list Unitize[mat], {x, y}]
```

> a1 + e1 x + m1 x^3 + f1 x y + j1 x^2 y + g1 x y^2 + d1 y^3

Answer (score 3):

Adapting an example from the documentation for `CoefficientList`:

```
Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, Unitize@mat*list, {x, y}]
(*  a1 + e1 x + m1 x^3 + f1 x y + j1 x^2 y + g1 x y^2 + d1 y^3  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Terse:

```
Total[Array[x^# y^#2 &, {4, 4}, 0] list Unitize@mat, 2]
```

> ```
> a1 + e1 x + m1 x^3 + f1 x y + j1 x^2 y + g1 x y^2 + d1 y^3
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to tell Mathematica where the zero coefficients are, but if you do that it can be done like so:

```
list = {{a1, 0, 0, d1}, {e1, f1, g1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, l1}, {m1, 0, 0, 0}}; 
Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, list, {x, y}] // Expand
```

> `a1 + e1 x + m1 x^3 + f1 x y + g1 x y^2 + d1 y^3 + l1 x^2 y^3`

This is discussed in the documentation of [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) in the section **Properties & Relations**.